# Adding new Product Variant is also automatically added another Variant

Tags: rest, shopify

When I add new Product Variant, it successfully added the Product Variant but it also added another Variant named "Default Title", my request looks like this:

```
POST /admin/products/#{id}/variants.json

{
  "variant": {
    "name":"Purple",
    "option1": "Purple"
  }
}
```

If this is the first Product Variant, it added automatically another Product Variant with name of "Default Title". **These 2 are visible in storefront and admin view.**

Answer (score 0):

Shopify products always have at least one variant. If you try to create a product without any variants then Shopify will create a default one, and any additional one you add would be the second variant.

If you want to, you can include the variants when you create the product. That looks like this:

```
POST /admin/products.json HTTP/1.1
Host: yourstore.myshopify.com
Content-Type: application/json
X-Shopify-Access-Token: abc123

{
  "product": {
    "title": "Cool scarf",
    "variants": [
      {
        "title": "Purple",
        "option1": "Purple"
      }
    ],
    "options": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "position": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can find out more from the examples in the Products API documentation: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product